# REST API pattern for this usecase

Tags: rest, api, api-design

I need to achieve this via an AJAX call, where a handy helper function (on the server) would do the trick, yet what is the REST way of doing it?

I have a list of items(cats) at the browser side, And I need to populate another detail for all those items.

```
input = [list of cat ids]
output = [list of {}s which has cat ids & age]
```

If I need not to care about proper REST API, I would just declare a method populate_cat_details() and would invoke it via GET http://example.com?method=populate_cat_details&cat_ids=1,2,3,4 that returns a JSON

Comment: This is *too broad*. "_Questions which are too broad, unclear, incomplete or primarily opinion-based may be [put on hold by the community](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) until they are improved._" see _[What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GET http://www.example.com/cats    -> return all cats
GET http://www.example.com/cats/:id    -> return 1 cat by id
GET http://www.example.com/cats?id=x&id=y&id=z -> return n cats matching ids
GET http://www.example.com/cats?age=2&age=3&age=4  -> return n cats matching ages 
GET http://www.example.com/cats?id=x&id=y&id=z&age=2&age=3&age=4  -> return n cats matching ids and ages
```

You have other ways if passing parameters like coma-separated values ex: ids=1,2,3

take a look here:
http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/restfulresourcenaming.html

Comment: So the idea is, get full details of cats for the input list, which is not just limited to age since it includes all other properties. 

In a way, I would say this is a good answer. Though it transmits unwanted details to the client/browser.